# Postfix acting weird: relay access denied

Tags: debian, postfix

my e-mail-server Postfix+Cyrus was running for over 7 days and suddenly I get this error 554 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied (state 14) when I try to send or recieve mail.
Postfix worked fine and nothing was changed. There is enough RAM and LoadAverage is 0.56. Any suggestions where to start investigating (Ubuntu LTS 10.04)? This is quite strange, if I restart the whole server the mails are fine again.

Thank you for your help

LOG:

Jan 24 00:35:56 mailserver postfix/smtpd[783]: connect from mail-qy0-f174.google.com[209.85.216.174]
Jan 24 00:35:56 mailserver postfix/smtpd[783]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-qy0-f174.google.com[209.85.216.174]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=ESMTP helo=
Jan 24 00:35:57 mailserver postfix/smtpd[783]: disconnect from mail-qy0-f174.google.com[209.85.216.174]

Comment: please, add log

Comment: osdyng - I added the log

Comment: You mentioned that restarting the server resolved the issue... but for how long?

Comment: Once the server was running for 90 days, now around 7 days. I am afraid that I need to do it more often =(

Answer (score 1):

Check mydestination:

```
# postconf | grep "^mydestination"
```

Postfix does't see itself as being destination for domain and rejects the mail

Comment: tells me > hash:/etc/postfix/mydestination | there are all domains I use listed with OK behind it.

Comment: use postmap to refresh /etc/postfix/mydestination